# OpenGL ES - Rendering a particle effect with additive blending (FBO)

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

How do you correctly render a particle effect, which have particles that are blended additively, on top of a background image?

Problem is the particles are also blended additively with the background, how can I avoid that? (i.e blend them additively to each other but not to the background as well)

Some additional constraints:

The game I'm working on is rendered in 8 layers as follows:

1. Background #1 (parallax scrolling)
2. Background #2 (parallax scrolling)
3. Background #3 (parallax scrolling)
4. Particle Effects Layer #1
5. Game Objects
6. Particle Effects Layer #2
7. UI
8. Particle Effects Layer #3

If FBO is the only way to go to solve the blending problem, should I use 8 textures (with screen dimensions), and render each layer separately to the FBO, then rendering the 8 textures to the window frame buffer? that seems too memory consuming. Using a single texture will require 16 FBO switches...

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Can you draw all the particles first against a black clearcolor, and then draw your 'background' afterwards behind them? You can use depth buffer to place the background behind the particles.

This will only work if there's no partial transparency required for your particles though.

Comment: I see what you mean, it may work. what do you mean by no partial transparency? what will happen?